# Was the warehouse at the end of Raiders based on any real-life equivalent?

Tags: real-location, indiana-jones, raiders-of-the-lost-ark

I'm sure people probably recall the scene I'm talking about, but here's a recap:

At the conclusion of Raiders of the Lost Ark, Indy is assured that the Ark of the Covenant is in a "safe place" where, according to a guy who seems to be some government lackey, "our top men are working on it". Scene cuts to shots of the Ark being placed in a wooden crate, stencilled with "Top Secret Army Intel #9906753, Do Not Open!" and then wheeled away into the depths of a very large and mysterious/ominous-looking warehouse full of similarly marked crates.

YouTube:

Of course, we later discover in Crystal Skull that this warehouse is part of a (fictionalised) US Army base located in Area 51.

I am wondering whether this warehouse, which basically appears to be a US government equivalent of the "Department of Mysteries" in Harry Potter, was based on any particular real-life location or facility serving the same, or a similar, purpose?

Obviously I'm not talking about the US army base in Area 51, or the physical architecture of the actual warehouse building, but rather a place where the government stores items that it wants to keep hidden and secure from the rest of the world.

Also, I am sure that organisations like the CIA and NSA must have some locations that serve such a purpose, but I am after a **specific example that is cited by the writers/producers/Spielberg and Lucas etc. in real life,** not just easily inferred generalisations or speculation (I would welcome that kind of commentary in the comments, but NOT posted as answers).

Comment: If Lucas/Spielberg say the warehouse is really part of Area 51, that's a pretty specific example being cited right there. Beyond that, why would you think that Lucas/Spielberg would have any first-hand knowledge of such a facility?

Comment: I'd say the closest thing in the real world is maybe the Smithsonian Archive...if there was an object that was out-of-place, or needed protection for historical reasons, that's probably where it would go.

Comment: If such a place existed outside of what we think of as Area 51, or the Smithsonian, filled with potentially deadly, or even catastrophic devices so dangerous even the government wouldn't touch them, would they ever allow such information into the general public? The best we could hope to do is to consider facilities such as museums to be extensive archives of deadly objects locked in the basement while replicas pretend to be those objects upstairs. Hiding them in plain sight as it were...

Comment: My empoyer told me just this week that he's been to that warehouse, actually. I would assume from that that it really exists. I didn't ask him where it was though, so I can offer no more details.

Comment: @phantom42 I would not count their placement of the warehouse in Area 51 within the movie as them "saying" that such a thing is there in real life. If they have said as such in interviews etc. (in a "real world" context, not in their works of fiction), I would consider that to be an acceptable answer but as it currently stands that's not what I'm after.

Comment: You want to know what real-life building with a similar purpose Lucas/Spielberg may have been referencing. The movie depicts a theorized Area 51. [Area 51 has been confirmed to be real](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/08/15/area-51-location-government-aliens_n_3764267.html) - granted, years after the movie came out.Any place where the government is *hiding secrets* is going to be secret itself - much like Area 51 was supposed to be. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Does the 'Well of Souls' have a real equivalent?  Watching the clip you kindly included, there's no visible credentials lanyard on the attendant, and his attire is all wrong, and he wouldn't be using a hand cart anyway,  thus no evidence that it is a government facility other than the stencils.  The final scene is simply a visual metaphor for reburying the ark in a place it will never be found.

Comment: @phantom42 Yes, "secrets are secret", but just because a location contains stuff that is meant to be kept secret doesn't mean the location itself would be a secret. E.g. The oft-portrayed "situation room" of the White House is a real place and although we don't know exactly what is said and done in there at any given moment, we know it exists and are aware of its general purpose. Re: "what else are you looking for", my question states that I am after something **specifically cited by (i.e. spoken or written by) Lucas/Spielberg etc., IRL, as a model for/analogue of the movie warehouse.** :)

Comment: I have edited my question for greater clarity. Also thanks for the article link @phantom42 , I had not been aware that the government has actually confirmed its existence :)

Comment: Hmmm, secret warehouse, full of mysterious objects, some with unknown powers.  Does this sound like Warehouse 13 to anybody?

Comment: @GarryVass - Why (especially in the early 1940's) wouldn't he be using a handcart?

Comment: As far as Area 51, while I have not been in any buildings, I have been inside the fence of the research area north of Nellis AFB in Nevada. I was a medic out of the ER and had to go pick someone up. Searched in and out of the ambo, mirrors under while in a cordoned section between two fences. Escorted to a building fore and aft by MP's, patient was already outside (Not allowed to enter), escorted back and searched again on way out. MP stayed with patient entire time in full armed gear.

Comment: @JohnP, the military started using vehicular forklifts in large warehouses in world war 1, and by the time the movie took place it was well ramped up.  And in terms of continuity, at the time the movie took place (late 30's), Area 51 consisted of a dirt runway and a dusty control tower.

Comment: Tangentially, the [Government Warehouse List](http://www.prismnet.com/~jlockett/RPG/HEGGA/Stuff/warehouse.html) is a lot of fun.

Comment: It's a good question. I have top men working on it.

Comment: that's clearly not an answer you should visit the [help] and specially [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section

Answer (score 5):

You can see a government document storage facility (in Houston, Texas) on the ActivRac website here. It's not quite as dramatically lit as the movie version I'm afraid;

[image]

Comment: The question was asking about warehouses specifically used for hiding items. Is the storage facility you posted about used for this function>

Comment: In-universe, it's not clear that the warehouse is anything other than "a big warehouse", the implication being that if you bury it, someone will simply dig it up again whereas if you hide something in plain sight within a large bureaucratic system, it's unlikely to ever be opened again.

Comment: Not really what I was after but still interesting, thanks :)

Comment: I find it unlikely that the US really has a "Warehouse 13 / Area 51" where they store things that they don't want to see the light of day. The only things I could think of that would fall into that category would be seized weaponry or spy equipment, both of which probably would be kept within R+D depts at places like Walbridge Army Research Lab or the NSA laboratory at Fort Meade

Comment: @Valorum Frankly, I like to think we'd file all our super-secret stuff under something no one would ever *want* to read that still has controls for when people need to access it, like "Protected Tax Data (Prior to 1930)" or from a fake, but real-and-dreary-sounding agency, like "The International Committee for the Regulation of Embassy Food Quality: Minor Snacks Subcommittee."

Answer (score 2):

One place that's used is the Federal Depository at Fort Knox.  Several items are stored there on request of other nations. Such as the Hungarian Crown Jewels. There are others but that's the only one I know of for sure.

Comment: This would be the Hungarian Crown Jewels, not the (vastly more valuable) British Crown Jewels.